# floating two adjacent elements affects fourth element

Tags: css, css-float

Sorry for the confusing title, if someone has a title which explains the issue better please edit it.

I am trying to create an input form with floats.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jtn507w/
HTML:

```
<div>
    <label class="Label"> label1 </label>
    <input type="text"class="inp1"/>
    <select class="select1">
        <option value="something"> something</option>
    </select>


    <label class="Label lbl2"> label2 </label>
    <select  class="select2">
        <option value="somethingelse">somethingelse</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Label{
    float:left;
}
inp1{

    float:left;
}
```

what I want is "label1, inp1 and select1" on the first line in this order. Then "label2 and select2" on the second line in this order.

For soe reason label2 moves in front of label1.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix?

thanks.

PS. I know this can be done simply by adding a `<br />` tag between rows, but in my mind what I am doing should work too so I want to clear my concepts as to why it is not working and how to do it using floats.

Comment: you will required some container like `p` which will contain your `label` `input` and `select` element. like this. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/7jtn507w/2/

Comment: Your have two many option first is this you can define .select1{
    
    float:left;
}
  Demo is this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazadwincere/7jtn507w/5/

Answer (score 1):

["A floated box must have an explicit width..."](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) If no width is set, the results can be unpredictable.

In your case, you should enclose your input elements in a `div` like this

```
<div>
    <div class="input-row">
        <label class="Label"> label1 </label>
        <input type="text"class="inp1"/>
        <select class="select1">
        <option value="something"> something</option>
        </select>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-row">  
        <label class="Label lbl2"> label2 </label>
        <select  class="select2">
        <option value="somethingelse">somethingelse</option>
        </select>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way, you're adding a block element containing several floating children. Its also a good idea to append a `clearfix` to each input-row.

```
.clearfix { clear: both; }
```

Comment: "Floating an element causes its blockness to go away." What? No, if anything, floating an element *forces it to be a block*.

Comment: What I mean here is, the floating element doesn't automatically spread across the width unless explicitly done. Doesn't it? Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to following

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7jtn507w/6/)**

```
<div>
    <label class="Label"> label1 </label>
    <input type="text"class="inp1"/>
    <select class="select1">
        <option value="something"> something</option>
    </select>
</div>
      <div>  
    <label class="Label lbl2"> label2 </label>
    <select  class="select2">
        <option value="somethingelse">somethingelse</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Label{
    float:left;
}
inp1{

    float:left;
}
```

Comment: With your HTML, you don't need to float anymore: [**edited Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jtn507w/19/).

Answer (score 0):

you would required some container like `p` which will contain  `input`, `select`, `label` elements. Since all these elements are `inline` elements so no need to use `float` here. check **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/7jtn507w/2/)**.

```
<div>
     <p>
        <label class="Label"> label1 </label>
        <input type="text"class="inp1"/>
        <select class="select1">
         <option value="something"> something</option>
        </select>
    <p>
    <p>  
        <label class="Label lbl2"> label2 </label>
        <select  class="select2">
         <option value="somethingelse">somethingelse</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answers are correct, I though it would be a good addition to mention you CAN do just about anything with css.

Any element can become a block element if you tell it to.

changing the css a bit got the results you asked for, as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jtn507w/16/)

The main change was to make all elements block and supply a width

```
label, input, select{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:30%;
}
```

One tricky thing is selects never like to be consistent with their width and height as opposed to other form elements, so they needed to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of what `float` does or can do, and what you should (not) do with it needs an update. But the whole float story is way too long to write down here, so you'll have to google that yourself.

Your problem however, is very easy to fix: remove the float declarations and replace them with this div width limitation:

```
div {
    300px;
}
```

See the [**edited Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jtn507w/20/).

Labels, inputs and selects are inline elements, behave just like text.